# Adafruit Snake Eyes Bonnet - TFTs backlit but no image

Tags: adafruit

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B with the Adafruit Snake Eyes bonnet and 2x IPS TFT ST7789.

I've soldered it all up, I can't see any bridging and I've done continuity checks on each pin.
I've done a fresh install of Buster OS Lite Legacy and run through the software setup on the guide - https://learn.adafruit.com/animated-snake-eyes-bonnet-for-raspberry-pi/

When the Pi boots, I can see the animated eyes if I plug in a HDMI cable, however the TFT screens are backlit but don't display anything at all.

I've run the following command:

```
sudo i2cdetect -y 1
```

Which returns:

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Does this mean the Pi can't see the TFTs?
I'm quite new to this so any guidance appreciated. What would be the next step to troubleshoot?

Comment: there are no I2C devices detected ... check the wiring ... please post a clear, well lit, closeup picture of the soldering job

Comment: Shouldn't your first stop be the Adafruit forums? They have pretty good support and a re the experts on this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry please ignore this question - the guys at Adafruit have responded to say it's a poor soldering job.

Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).